# .htaccess forwarding specific files to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, forwarding

I am cleaning up my root directory, and it has a lot of "trash" inside.

so i am moving all the files so a subfolder "oldroot"

now, some of my users are using some of the trash files....but only 3-4 files....is there an easy and quick way to configure .htaccess to forward **these specific files only**, like

```
mypage1.php ==> oldroot/mypage1.php
mypage2.php ==> oldroot/mypage2.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.htaccess file` use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^(mypage1|mypage2|mypage3)\.php$    oldroot/$1.php    [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

It will work for any file that you move to `oldroot` i.e. all of the files that you want to leave in the root will be served from there.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if the file exists in the oldroot directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldroot%{REQUEST_URI} -f [NC]
# then serve the file from oldroot
RewriteRule ^ /oldroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```